# Python adding missing rows based on a single column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two colums of interest: a column with names (repeated for each course), and a column with the course name they've taken or started. The problem is, if I use the dataframe as-is, if a person has not attempted the course, they won't have a value showing for that course at all, and therefore I won't be able to tell who is missing the course. Is there a way to auto generate the missing rows with a name? The other columns can be N/A or anything else.

Dataframe:

| Name | Course Title | Completion Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Math | 1/1/2021 |
| Mark | English | 2/1/2021 |
| Mark | Econ | 3/1/2021 |
| David | Math | 7/1/2021 |
| David | English | 4/1/2021 |
| Cindy | Math | 6/1/2021 |
| Cindy | English | 9/1/2021 |
| Cindy | Econ | 11/1/2021 |

What I'm looking for:

| Name | Course Title | Completion Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mark | Math | 1/1/2021 |
| Mark | English | 2/1/2021 |
| Mark | Econ | 3/1/2021 |
| David | Math | 7/1/2021 |
| David | English | 4/1/2021 |
| **David** | **Econ** | **N/A** |
| Cindy | Math | 6/1/2021 |
| Cindy | English | 9/1/2021 |
| Cindy | Econ | 11/1/2021 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make missing values explicit with the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.complete.html#janitor.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/index.html):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.complete('Name', 'Course Title')

    Name Course Title Completion Date
0  Cindy         Econ       11/1/2021
1  Cindy      English        9/1/2021
2  Cindy         Math        6/1/2021
3  David         Econ             NaN
4  David      English        4/1/2021
5  David         Math        7/1/2021
6   Mark         Econ        3/1/2021
7   Mark      English        2/1/2021
8   Mark         Math        1/1/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pivot` and `stack` with `reset_index`:

```
>>> df.pivot(*df).stack(dropna=False)[::-1].reset_index(name='Completion Date')
    Name Course Title Completion Date
0   Mark         Math        1/1/2021
1   Mark      English        2/1/2021
2   Mark         Econ        3/1/2021
3  David         Math        7/1/2021
4  David      English        4/1/2021
5  David         Econ             NaN
6  Cindy         Math        6/1/2021
7  Cindy      English        9/1/2021
8  Cindy         Econ       11/1/2021
>>>
```

If you specifically want it to be `N/A`, try:

```
>>> df.pivot(*df).stack(dropna=False)[::-1].reset_index(name='Completion Date').fillna('N/A')
    Name Course Title Completion Date
0   Mark         Math        1/1/2021
1   Mark      English        2/1/2021
2   Mark         Econ        3/1/2021
3  David         Math        7/1/2021
4  David      English        4/1/2021
5  David         Econ             N/A
6  Cindy         Math        6/1/2021
7  Cindy      English        9/1/2021
8  Cindy         Econ       11/1/2021
>>>
```